# How to implement click event on a image in picture scroll field?

Tags: blackberry

How to implement click event on a image in picture scroll field?

Answer (score 2):

sorry, but override `touchEvent` doesn't work, but try to override `trackwheelClick`:

```
PictureScrollField pictureScrollField = new PictureScrollField(150, 100){
    protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {
     return super.trackwheelClick(status,time);  

    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override touchEvent

```
PictureScrollField pictureScrollField = new PictureScrollField(150, 100) {
        protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
            if (TouchEvent.CLICK == message.getEvent()) {
                FieldChangeListener listener = getChangeListener();
                if (null != listener)                       
                    listener.fieldChanged(this, 1);
                    return true;
            }
            return super.touchEvent(message);
        }                   
    };
```

and then add FieldChangeListener:

```
      pictureScrollField.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {          
        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {                
            if (context == 1) {
              Dialog.alert("click:" + ((PictureScrollField)field).getCurrentImageIndex());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i have a problem with clicked pictureScrollField ..... the logic of the problem is : after clicking on pictureScrollField icon . i delete the pictureScrollField . the problem ocurre after deleting pictureScrollField cause the action occure on any foucs field. ( after deleting the pictureScrollField from the manager the focus change to another field and executes its action ) ..... how can i delete the pictureScrollField without executing the other field action